# What is considered as best practice for defining common types in golang?

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns, go, golang

We have set of common types (mostly structs, scalars, string IDs) that are used across different packages in a project written in Golang. Currently we define them in a package named "models" in the root of the project. It was made to reduce cohesion of different packages and to avoid circular dependencies. Is it considered as good practice to achieve these goals this way? If no, what are the alternative approaches?

Comment: Cohesion is usually considered a *good* thing - are you sure the designers intentionally decreased it?

Comment: @KilianFoth , maybe I've used wrong term. I meant that we strive to make packages not depend from each other, but from abstract interfaces (that are defined where consumed) and common things. That let us keep the package dependencies graph simple.

Comment: @KilianFoth , so the sake of the question is: what is the best practice to manage such "common things", and is keeping them in the single package "models" considered as good practice?

Comment: @oare234, where I work we generally create a module called `lib` with all of the shared packages. We also follow a release process to version them so we can do a `go get ...` if needed with the changes we are after.